# ManifestEntries when building jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest.mf

I am trying to set my build server information into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. It works very well when using maven-jar-plugin with manifestEntries . The problem is that when I am packaging the Jar with maven-assembly-plugin to a single Jar with dependencies (like in here: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)) I can't see my manifest entries anymore. My guess is that my MANIFEST.MF is being dropped, while the assembly runs, but I could not find the way to set it after the manifest completes.

This is how my pom.xml build section looks like:

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ConvertorMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Application-Version>${app.version.major}.${app.version.minor}.0</Application-Version>
                        <Built-By>${user}</Built-By>
                        <Git-Branch>${git.branch}</Git-Branch>
                        <Git-Commit>${git.commit}</Git-Commit>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
...
</build>
```

Without the jar-with-dependencies, the MAINFEST.MF will contain:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Git-Commit: 35ff1f997b0c01daf44ed23425a3dc93307faaf7
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_03
Built-By: Build Server
Git-Branch: origin/HEAD
Created-By: Apache Maven
Application-Version: 0.2.57
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Then, unzip -q -c convertor-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF dumps:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: eranh
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
Main-Class: ConvertorMain
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have simply to copy the archive section from your maven-jar-plugin configuration into the maven-assembly-plugin as well.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I am sure I tried it sometime along my endless tries - probably did it wrong...:)

Comment: After the copy, you can remove completely the `maven-jar-plugin` definition.